# dropdown is getting messed up in the menu header

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am working on making menu header for my webpage. Here is my [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tne4zh8h/5/).

In my menu header, my dropdown is not working properly on `INSURANCE` text. Once you click it, you will see what I meant. I am not able to figure out what's wrong. And I believe it is mainly happening because of `height` and `overflow` on `.topnav` but not sure what is the best way to fix it?

Here is my HTML and CSS:

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: AvantGarde Demi;
  src: url(AvantGarde Demi.woff);
}
@font-face {
  font-family: AvantGarde;
  src: url(AvantGarde.woff);
}
@font-face {
  font-family: ITC Avant Garde Gothic;
  src: url(ITC Avant Garde Gothic.woff);
}
/******************For Top Nav****************************/
.topnav {
  position: relative;
  top: -890px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  height: 89px;
  border-bottom: 3px solid #EF7440;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.topnav ul>li {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
}
.topnav a {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
  color: white;
  display: block;
}
/* dropdown menus hidden initially */

.topnav ul > li > ul {
  display: none;
  margin-top: 30px;
  width: 200px;
  padding: 0;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f76c38;
}
.topnav ul > li > ul > li {
  float: left;
  clear: left;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}
body {
  border: 0;
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
.header {
  position: relative;
  height: 769px;
}
.header-background {
  height: 769px;
  width: 100%;
}
.orange-bar {
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 150px;
  top: -430px;
  left: -160px;
}
.header h1 {
  padding-left: 110px;
  color: white;
  font-family: AvantGarde;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 35px;
  left: -420px;
  letter-spacing: .24em;
  position: relative;
  top: -615px;
  font-family: "AvantGarde";
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
.header p {
  padding-left: 290px;
  text-align: center;
  padding-right: 210px;
  font-size: 22px;
  letter-spacing: .12em;
  font-family: "Adelle PE";
  color: white;
  position: relative;
  top: -700px;
}
.header h2 {
  font-family: "Adelle PE";
  font-style: italic;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  top: -490px;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 21px;
  position: relative;
  margin-left: 630px;
  color: white;
  letter-spacing: 0.24em;
}
.header a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}
#worldofnorthman {
  background-size: cover;
  background-image: url("our_story.png");
  /*width: 404px;*/
  height: 768px !important;
}
.login {
  display: inline;
  padding-left: 15px;
  letter-spacing: .25em;
  color: white;
  font-size: 11.433px;
  font-family: AvantGarde;
}
.login a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.login a:hover {
  color: #fe5b1f;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.container {
  width: 100% !important;
}
li.insurance {
  padding-top: 30px !important;
}
li.our-story {
  padding-top: 30px !important;
}
li.login-signup {
  padding-top: 30px !important;
}
li.get-covered {
  margin-top: 15px;
  padding-bottom: 10px !important;
  padding-top: 10px !important;
}
li.our-story {
  margin-right: 200px !important;
  font-family: AvantGarde;
  letter-spacing: .30em;
  color: white;
}
li.login-signup {
  font-style: italic;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-family: Adelle PE;
  letter-spacing: .30em;
  color: white;
}
li.get-covered {
  border-color: #EF7440;
  border-style: solid;
  color: white;
  letter-spacing: .30em;
  font-family: Adelle PE;
}
li.get-covered:hover {
  background-color: #EF7440;
}
li.insurance {
  margin-right: 80px;
  margin-left: 80px;
  color: white;
  font-family: AvantGarde;
  letter-spacing: .30em;
}
```

```html
<div class="header"> <img class="header-background" src="https://s30.postimg.org/3q4ox3s81/background-image-chrisdavenport.png">
  <div class="orange-bar">
      <img class="orange-bar-image" src="https://s9.postimg.org/sdrolfjan/orange-bar.png">
  </div>
  <div class="topnav">
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li class="home"><img src="https://s2.postimg.org/nhr4xxqcp/northman_wordmark_CMYK.png">
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#"><b>INSURANCE</b> <i class="fa fa-angle-down" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-content">
                <li><a href="#"><i>INDIVIDUAL</i></a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#"><i>CORPORATE</i></a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="our-story">OUR STORY</li>
        <li class="login-signup">Log In | Sign up</li>
        <li class="get-covered">GET <strong style="font-style:italic">COVERED</strong>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
  <h1 class="text-inside-orange">INSURANCE FOR THE WILD</h1>
</div>
```

Any thoughts what I did wrong? Also I want to align everything in menu header in one line and my dropdown should start from the border of that orange line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You used overflow hidden in navigation div which caused the problem. Here's the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tne4zh8h/9/)

```
.topnav {
    position: relative;
    top: -890px;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    height: 89px;
    border-bottom: 3px solid #EF7440;
    /*overflow: hidden;*/
}
```

Comment: got it.. how can I align them properly in one line so that in our menu header everything comes in one straight line.. Also dropdown should start from border of that orange line. Any thoughts how can we do this?

Comment: Also after you remove hidden part in your jsfiddle, I see there is a gap in the top of the page now where my menu bar is there and it was not there earlier..

Comment: Here's another [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tne4zh8h/8/). I am trying to align the nav menu. Let me know if any other help needed.

Comment: looks good now.. one thing I see is if you look at the top of the page, you will see menu bar is showing a little bit at the bottom of the page and there is a gap in the starting.. Any idea why it is like that?

Comment: check this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tne4zh8h/9/). topnav class margin need to increse. Don't forget to mark my answer as right.

Comment: looks good.. I am accepting your answer. If I have any doubts I will check with you later on.. Thanks for all your help!